# Which directory to place images for the html src attribute to work?

Tags: html, css, sinatra, png, slim

For some reason, in my sinatra app which is currently using slim, whenever I attempt to place an image in my markup with the html `src="path/to/file"`, the image appears on the site as the stock photo icon, and sometimes even returns a 404.

All images are kept in an images directory, and setting a css background-image from an image in this directory works fine. But for some reason the html img src attribute does not return the image after specifying it's directory location.

All images are pngs.

Thanks for any help,
-Adam

For extra information:

I store set my public folder to a director called assets with

```
set :public_folder => 'assets'
```

This assets folder is located at the project base, and inside assets is a folder called "images" which contains my png.

What's bizarre is that even after defining an explicit path like
img src="/Users/*user*/Desktop/Programming/Sinatra-projects/*projectname*/assets/images/image.png"

it still doesn't display, and shows a stock photo icon.

AND, it successfully loads other images in this directory with the location syntax
src="/images/*image*.png"

Comment: Can you please add example link?

Answer (score 0):

I think you configure your static folder wrong you may look at the documentation http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Static%20Files

`set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/static'`

Comment: Yes, I use "set :public_folder => 'assets'" where assets contains my images directory that stores the png.

Answer (score 0):

Within application `root`, if a folder `public` exists static setting is enabled. In default circumstances, image should reside in `public/path/to/file`. Where as to refer it, you may want to use absolute path like `/path/to/file` instead of `path/to/file`. In case you are referring to it within nested folders with relative path, image will end up 404. You can read more about [Sinatra Configuration](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) to tweak the settings as desired.